# Allow actions based on Meteor.user() porperties?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to allow adding and deleting from my Meteor collections based on a user property.

This is how I set up my admin user:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {

        Accounts.createUser({
        username:'Greg',
        password:'default',
        isAdmin: 1
        });

    }

}
```

I now want to allow every user with isAdmin = true to create another user via Accounts.createUser:

```
Meteor.methods({
    makeUser: function(attributes) {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        if (user.isAdmin)
            Accounts.createUser(attributes)
        else
            console.log('User ' + user.username + ' created a player.')
    }  
})
```

The user is never created as if user.isAdmin never equals true. What am I doing wrong? Is this related to publishing and subscribing? At the moment I still have autopublish switched on.

Comment: If I change my code to isAdmin: 'admin' and if (user.isAdmin = 'admin') it always equals true and every user is allowed to use makeUser.

Comment: If you write in your developers console Meteor.user() what you get?

Comment: Only my ID and my username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add flag `isAdmin` to profile object:

```
Accounts.createUser({
        username:'Greg',
        password:'default',
        profile:{
          isAdmin: 1
        }  
});
```

See [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser)

`Accounts.createUser` methods allows to add ONLY fields `username`, `password`, `email` and `profile`  to user object.

```
Meteor.methods({
    makeUser: function(attributes) {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        if (user.profile && user.profile.isAdmin)
            Accounts.createUser(attributes)
        else
            console.log('User ' + user.username + ' created a player.')
    }  
})
```

### Update

Consider using package [roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles).

Comment: By default users can write to their own `profile`. You'll want to disable that or else anyone can make themselves an admin.

Comment: Via: Meteor.users.deny({update: function () { return true; }});?

Comment: Take a look on package [roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles). It creates field `user.roles` and give you API to easily check user role.

Answer (score 0):

In that case normal user can still call `Accounts.createUser` and completely bypass your `makeUser` to create a user, which I don't think it's what the behaviour you want to see.
I would suggest wrapping `Accounts.onCreateUser` with the isAdmin logic from @Kuba Wyrobek:

```
// server side
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    user.profile = options.profile ? options.profile : {};
    if (user.profile && user.profile.isAdmin) {
        return user;
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Forbbiden");
    }
});
```